# Pushforward of a degree $d$ map $f: \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^n$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology

Consider a rational curve of degree $d$ in the complex projective space $\mathbb{P}^n$, which is given by a map $$f: \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^n, \quad [x_0,x_1] \mapsto [f_0(x_0,x_1), \dots, f_n(x_0,x_1)],$$
where each $f_i$ is a homogeneous polynomial of degree $d$.

Then we have a pushforward in the second homology groups
$$f_*: H_2(\mathbb{P}^1) \to H_2(\mathbb{P}^n).$$

Let $[\mathbb{P}^1]$ denote the fundamental class of $\mathbb{P}^1$ and $[L]$ the homology class of a line in $\mathbb{P}^n$, which generates $H_2(\mathbb{P}^n)$. It's known that

$$f_*[\mathbb{P}^1] = d[L].$$

**How to prove the above formula?**

Note that $f_*[\mathbb{P}^1]$ is not the homology class of the image curve $f(\mathbb{P}^1)$ in general. For example, consider $f: \mathbb{P}^1 \to \mathbb{P}^1, \ [x_0,x_1] \mapsto [x_0^d, x_1^d]$. Then $f_*[\mathbb{P}^1] = d[\mathbb{P}^1]$, but $[f(\mathbb{P}^1)]=[\mathbb{P}^1]$.

Comment: If you're willing to accept a solution through intersection theory, this is just the fact that the product $f_*[\Bbb P^1]\cdot H=d$ inside the Chow ring. Are you looking for a different solution?

Comment: @KReiser I was looking for a direct proof using singular/simplicial homology. But how do you prove $f_*[\mathbb{P}^1] \cdot H = d$ in the Chow ring?

Comment: The intersection of $f_*[\Bbb P^1]$ and $H$ has degree $d$ by Bezout, so it's $d$ points counted with appropriate multiplicites. But we can separate those multiple points in to distinct points using rational equivalence, so the equality $H\cdot f_*[\Bbb P^1]=d[pt]$ holds.

Comment: @KReiser I'm not sure if Bezout's theorem applies here. The question boils down to an understanding of $f_*[\mathbb{P}^1]$. Can you explain more about this?

Comment: My brain and typing fingers aren't quite in sync right now - give me a bit and let me see if I can't write my thoughts more clearly as an answer.

Comment: @KReiser There is a similar question in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715594/relation-between-different-definitions-of-degree-in-complex-geometry?rq=1). The answer there explained why $\text{deg}\ f_*[\mathbb{P}^1] = d$ in this case.

Comment: That is essentially the sort of argument I had wanted to use. Does that resolve your current question or not?

Comment: @KReiser Yes, although it's different from what I expected.

Comment: Given your agreement that it resolves your question, I think this should be closed as a duplicate of that one. As a gold tag-badge holder, I can't suggest closure as a duplicate, I can only close as a duplicate (ie when I suggest a duplicate, the system closes it on the spot without the need for input from anyone else). If this is not acceptable to you, please say so, otherwise I'm going to close as a duplicate soon.